# Best solution for running visual studio on os x lion

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, virtualization

I have recently brought a macbook pro 13" and I have a .net project coming up. I am not sure what virtual machine to run visual studio 2010 ? There is the obvious option of installing it on bootcamp, but I've heard the performance is also very good whilst running it through virtual machine ?

Thanks (I've attached the specs below)

2.8GHz dual-core
Intel Core i7
4GB 1333MHz
750GB 7200-rpm1
Intel HD Graphics 3000

Answer (score 0):

With VMware Fusion (and possible Parallels) you can boot your BootCamp partition as a VM when running OS X.

Comment: Wow that's awesome, so I can use the bootcamp partition I've already setup whilst using a virtual machine?

Comment: Just be aware that you'll be sharing that 4GB of memory between OSX and the VM.